# Can you add notes via the Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to add notes via the Google Analytics API.  Ideally I would like to add a note whenever I send a social media post or send an email.  At the moment MailChimp will store the name of the campaign but I like to see notes so I can go through the various reports seeing where spikes are and instantly know why.

I've looked through the API documentation and I don't think this is supported.  Does anyone know differently?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still not possible. There is a feature request for the function via the Managment API (since 9 years). https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35352433

Comment: If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is still not possible. There is a feature request for the function via the Management API (since 10 years March 2010). https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35352433